# When should ga('require', 'linkid') be called in a single page application?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-analytics

I am currently developing a single page application in Ember and I am trying to implement Google Analytics [Enhanced Link Attribution](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en). (See my fork of [ember-cli-google-analytics](https://github.com/dehrax/ember-cli-google-analytics/tree/patch-1))

When am I supposed to call `ga('require', 'linkid)`? Is it on page load (in `<head>`), or is it on route change?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Hi! It should be called within the Router, or wherever your page actually changes content. I have not figured out how to get it to return the proper element id (the reference which Google Analytics uses). We have migrated to React and Redux, which makes it 1000 times easier to track user interactions.